# Implementing AOT in a project that is generated without AOT

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm wondering how I can implement / activate AOT (Ahead Of Time compilation) in a Angular CLI project that is generated without AOT.

Nowadays you can just generate a new app and use the --aot flag, but a while back this flag wasn't available. And guess what, my app is a few months old!

So I'm experimenting with AOT but couldn't find a clear way to implement it. First I thought I just needed:

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

But this was wrong.

Possible solution is to generate a new app with the flag and compare the files to see where the differences are. Did someone already accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing `AoT` specific to `ng mew`.

You should be able to just run `ng build --aot` (often used with `-prod`, although not a necessity) or `ng serve --aot` even.

Note that AoT has historically been half baked, in general, and especially in the CLI. Certain things would fail with it. The situation is much better in the latest @angular/compiler and Angular CLI versions, so, I suggest you try a new version and see.

```
npm uninstall --global angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install --global angular-cli
```

After that you can go to your existing project and run `ng init`, or try `ng new some-new-folder`, and copy your files there.

Then run `ng build -prod --aot` and see if you get errors you can fix (sometimes it asks for specific things), or if not, please create a new question with specific error.

**P.S.**

The only command that does not support AoT is `ng github-pages:deploy`, if you use it, you can use `ng github-pages:deploy --skip-build`, and run `ng build -prod --aot` before you call it.